# Jersey ChunkedOutput with Embedded Jetty on JDK 1.6

Tags: jersey, jetty, java-6

I'm trying to extend the example [here](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.0) to include a service using org.glassfish.jersey.server.ChunkedOutput ...

```
package com.example;
...

@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {

  @GET
  public ChunkedOutput<String> foo() {
    final ChunkedOutput<String> output = new ChunkedOutput<String>(
        String.class);

    new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          output.write("Hello world");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          //Empty
        } finally {
          try {
            output.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    }.start();

    return output;
  }
}
```

Ive added the following dependencies ...

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

The main with the Jetty setup looks like this ...

```
public class EmbedMe {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int port = 8080;
    Server server = new Server(port);

    String wardir = "target/sample-webapp-1-SNAPSHOT";

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setResourceBase(wardir);
    context.setDescriptor(wardir + "WEB-INF/web.xml");
    context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
        new AnnotationConfiguration(), new WebXmlConfiguration(),
        new WebInfConfiguration(), new TagLibConfiguration(),
        new PlusConfiguration(), new MetaInfConfiguration(),
        new FragmentConfiguration(), new EnvConfiguration() });

    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
    server.setHandler(context);

    // added for Jersey
    ServletHolder servletHolder = context.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/webapi/*");
    servletHolder.setAsyncSupported(true);
    servletHolder.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages","com.example");

    server.start();
    server.dump(System.err);
    server.join();
  }
}
```

When I run, I see this ...

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I think that's because I'm using jdk 1.6 and the jersey-container-jetty-http depends on jetty version 9.0.6.v20130930 (jdk 1.7).  The original code for the embedded Jetty / servlet 3 example uses jetty version 8.1.14.v20131031 and jdk 1.6.

So 3 questions

1. Is jersey-container-jetty-http the right dependency for the ChunkedOutput here?
2. Is it possible to use ChunkedOutput with embedded Jetty and JDK 1.6?
3. If it is possible, does anyone have a working example?